# How do I delete rows that are duplicated on specified columns?

Tags: python

I'm new in python.

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,3,2,2,2], 
 
                   'B':[1,5,5,1,1],
 
                    'C':[1,6,6,2,1],
                   'D':[1,2,3,1,1]})
df
```

dataframe:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   2   1   1   1
1   3   5   6   2
2   2   5   6   3
3   2   1   2   1
4   2   1   1   1
```

I want to delete the row and remain the first row, if column B and column C are both the same.

Like,

for row0 & row4, columnB and columnC are the same, delete row4;

for row1 & row2, columnB and columnC are the same, delete row2;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) on 'B' and 'C' columns (`subset=['B', 'C']`) and keep first (`keep='first'`)

```
>>> df.drop_duplicates(subset=['B', 'C'], keep='first')
   A  B  C  D
0  2  1  1  1
1  3  5  6  2
3  2  1  2  1
```

`keep='first'` is the default option so you don't have to set it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
df.groupby(['B', 'C']).head(1)
```

This takes the first element from each group:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  2  1  1  1
1  3  5  6  2
3  2  1  2  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
>>> df[~df[['B', 'C']].duplicated()]
   A  B  C  D
0  2  1  1  1
1  3  5  6  2
3  2  1  2  1
>>>
```